# Implementing custom user permissions in GraphQL and Hasura

Tags: permissions, graphql, hasura

I am creating a webapp that allows users to communicate in several different rooms and am hoping that I can use GraphQL and Hasura for this project. There will be admins which can create/delete rooms (wow-room, lol-Room, pubg-room), create/delete users, and create/delete permissions (admin, wow, lol, pubg) along with assigning roles to users. Users will be able to see any the rooms which they have the permisions to.

The problem is, I want to be sure that only the admins can create/delete these rooms/users/permisions and that only the correct users can see these rooms. Is there a way I can get Hasura to check the permissions of the given user and return the appropriate data? I believe that I need to write a custom resolver but am not sure how that is done or if it is the correct solution.

Comment: Hasura supports fine-grained access control. Check out the authorization docs:
https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/authorization/index.html

Comment: I was under the impression that doesn't support dynamic roles. Since an admin can create a room and will create various roles around the room, this may not apply. But I'll read through that again to see if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

While Hasura can handle dynamic roles (you can use the API to create new roles and new permission rules on the fly) with Hasura, I think in this case that's not required.

> The problem is, I want to be sure that only the admins can
>   create/delete these rooms/users/permisions and that only the correct
>   users can see these rooms. Is there a way I can get Hasura to check
>   the permissions of the given user and return the appropriate data?

Hasura allows you to set a permission rule that traverse relationships which makes this possible. Check out the [article-collaborators example in the Hasura docs](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/auth/authorization/common-roles-auth-examples.html#collaborators-of-an-article).

Assuming that your models are `rooms`, `users` and `room_users` and you have the relationships set up so that `room.users` returns the list of users for a particular room, the permission for a `user` role on the `rooms` table can be expressed as follows:

```
Allow SELECT on a row in rooms if
rooms.users.id: _eq: x-hasura-user-id
```

This translates to: if a room's users list contains atleast one *user_id* that is equal to *x-hasura-user-id* then grant access to that room.

I've set this up on a heroku app: https://multiple-roles-hasura.herokuapp.com/console/api-explorer

Try the following queries out in GraphiQL:

1. Set the headers to:

```
x-hasura-role: user
x-hasura-user-id: 1
```

2. Run the following query:

```
 query {
   rooms {
     id
     name
   }
 }
```

3. You'll see that the response only contains the rooms that **user1** has access to
4. Switch `x-hasura-user-id` through different values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and you'll see different results for the same query. Basically the right rooms that the only the current user has access to.

Checkout the models and the permissions for the models on:

- User & Room mappings: https://multiple-roles-hasura.herokuapp.com/console/data/schema/public/tables/room_users/browse
- Room permissions: https://multiple-roles-hasura.herokuapp.com/console/data/schema/public/tables/rooms/permissions